# how do I use an object in all scenes in UNITY2D or how do I research it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a project in UNITY 2D. In my Shop Scene there is a money bar that shows the money how much i have and also there is a counter that count the time. When I change the scene from here to another scene, also there should be a time counter and money bar. I can add manually. However, when I change the scene counter starts from 0 again. For money bar, I can pull the money from another scene. However, there will be more scene. It should be more complex. Is there a way to do a general object that runs in every scene without interrupt. Also, how can I research that more clearly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding DontDestroyOnLoad
after variables write

```
//Your variables here
public (classname) instance;

void Awake(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = gameObject; 
    }else{
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't create objects for use to same static work process in different scenes.
If you want to use same variable value for different scenes just simply use PlayerPreferences class. This class allows you to access the variables you have saved in the whole project regardless of the scenes.

[Please check instructions...](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

Example:

Imagine your method needs an integer value and you want to use different scenes same method.

**At scene1 =>**

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("variableName",(int)value)
```

**At scene2 =>**

*Get this value with* `PlayerPrefs.GetInt("variableName")` *and use it for your method.*